# Telegraf long interval (1 hour) and metrics retention

Tags: prometheus, grafana, telegraf

We have an input with a 1h interval. Telegraf collects said interval every hour but the metrics are dropped anywhere from 10-15 minutes.

Is there a way to control this and retain them longer? We scrape the metrics with Prometheus and would prefer to have a value returned and no gaps so we have Grafana table to show without the dreaded 'No Data'

Comment: Please also include your table information and code details which shows what you have done so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called [staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness). If your metric wasn't scraped for some time (5 minutes by default) it is marked as stale and is not returned by queries.

For metrics with such behaviour you can either use aggregation configuration of grafana's panel set to "Last* (*not null)" if dashboards time range bigger that one hour. Or you can solve this with function [`last_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time). Your query would look like this:

```
last_over_time(my_metric[1h])
```